# Categorical features driven perfect collinearity in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, multicollinearity, categorical-encoding

In OLS regression, when one has a set of sum-to-one dummies one needs to take one out to avoid perfect collinearity (be able to invert X^TX), in logistic regression as far as I understand one does not need to invert X^TX, so not obvious to me that one needs to do the same, was able to setup an optimizer to solve for a toy example (y ~ intercept + dummy_1 + dummy_2), with the estimated parameters in hand could fit the probabilities and corroborate they match the event rates by dummy group, the parameters on dummy_1 and dummy_2 have the convenience that one group has a positive coefficient and one has negative (given the intercept)

Question:

1. Is it a bad idea to include a perfect collinear design matrix due to dummy variables in logistic regression? The main reason to set up the problem like this is coefficient interpretation and significance (real use case includes multiple sets of sum-to-one dummies with many categories) am not interested in testing significance relative to an arbitrarily chosen reference category

Comment: Multicollinearity can lead to variance inflation of your parameters' standard errors.

Comment: Inversion is not the issue.  Logistic regression has *exactly* the same problems as OLS regression with reduced-rank design matrices $X:$ namely, the associated models are not identifiable.  There will be solutions, *but they won't be unique.*  If you're only interested in the fit, that's theoretically OK, but it can cause many algorithms to fail to recognize when they have achieved an adequate fit.

Comment: In OLS, the problem with rank-deficiency is that there are multiple *equally good* solutions; in other words, the coefficients are not unique. That's why your optimizer worked -- it just found *one solution among many*. This is explained in the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, so in OLS what I have seen is adding a restriction on the coefficients as to make the model identifiable, arguably one could try the same in logit model?

Comment: Yes; that's discussed in the duplicate.